# How to use the same PHP session in every fetch?

Tags: javascript, php, session, fetch

I am trying to make a simple authentication in Javascript using fetch to post credentials to a PHP file (login.php) inside this file it simply authenticates and add some values to $_SESSION and after receiving a response I immediately invoke another get fetch to (sessioninfo.php) and this php file simply returns the $_SESSION for testing purposes, but I received an empty array even though I already invoked session_start() in (sessioninfo.php) and (login.php).

I tried using axios and console.log the response and every response show different PHP Session ID, which I think the cause of why the $_SESSION is empty.

```js
fetch("http://localhost/login.php/", {
    method: 'POST',
    body: JSON.stringify({username: 'test', password: 'test'})    
})
.then(res => res.json())
.then(data => {
    fetch("http://localhost/sessioninfo.php")
    .then(res => res.json())
    .then(data => console.log(data));
});
```

Edited:

login.php

```js
<?php
session_start();
header("Content-Type: application/json");
require_once "../../pdo.php";

/**
 * @var PDO $pdo
 */

$data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);
$sql = "SELECT user_id from users WHERE username=:uname AND password=:pwd";
header("Content-Type: application/json");
$isInit = isset($data['username']) && isset($data['password']);
if($isInit) {
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare(
        $sql);
    $stmt->execute(array(
        ':uname' => $data['username'],
        ':pwd' => $data['password']
    ));
    $row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    
    if($row != false) {
        $sessionHash = hash('md5', $data['username'].$data['password'].$row['user_id']);
        $_SESSION['ca'] = $sessionHash;
        $_SESSION['user_id'] = $row['user_id'];
        $response = array('isAuth' => true, 'user_id' => $row['user_id'], 'ca' => $sessionHash, 'session' => $_SESSION);
        echo json_encode($response);
    }
    else {
        $response = array('isAuth' => false);
        echo json_encode($response);
    }
}
else {
    $response = array('message' => 'Missing input');
    echo json_encode($response);
}
```

I think there is no problem in login.php because I tested it with the right username and password and returns the right response

sessioninfo.php

```js
<?php
session_start();

echo json_encode($_SESSION);
```

Comment: Please show exactly what the PHP is doing. This _should_ work, really.

Comment: Okay, I already added the php files

Comment: You have a SQL injection bug here.